# Access internal forget gate value in lstm node

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have currently created an LSTM network using Keras and have to get the internal forget gate values for each node of the network. I have to get the forget gate/values everytime the predict() function is called. is it possible to do so?

If not then is there any other library which gives access to these internal gate values in a convenient manner at every step?

Looking forward to some help on this at the earliest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get internal weights and parameters?

If you are using `Keras` with `Tensorflow` backend (which is the recommended backend), you can access to the internal layer values (like weights & biases) using `tf.global_variables()`. For convenience, create a dictionary which map the layer names to the corresponding `tf.Variable`:

```python
variable_dict = dict([])
for variable in tf.global_variable():
    variable_dict[variable.name] = variable
```

After this simple mapping, you can refer to a variable directly by its name. The `LSTM` layer of Keras (let's say, the `model.summary()` shows that the LSTM layer is named as `'lstm_1'`) has the following internal variables: `'lstm_1/kernel:0'`, `'lstm_1/recurrent_kernel:0'`, and `'lstm_1/bias:0'`. To get their values, you will need to have some understanding of `Session` and `Tensor` objects of Tensorflow.

Now is the tricky part: how does Keras store the variables in these tensors? The documentation does not specify any information about it, so unfortunately you will have to refer to the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py). Look at the `LSTMCell` class, especially the `build` (describes which variables are defined) and `call` (describes how these variables are used in calculation) methods. Seems like the internal parameters are stored in the variables, named as `*_i`, `*_f`, `*_c`, `*_o` (e.g. `self.kernel_o`).

---

#### How to get in-between values during calculation?

Unfortunately, you will have to directly modify the calculation graph. It is easier than it sounds: just edit the Tensorflow's code and store these variables somewhere in a named tensor in the global scope.

---

> If not then is there any other library which gives access to these
>   internal gate values in a convenient manner at every step?

As you see, `Keras` with a `Tensorflow` backend is very convenient. I don't think that you can get any more convenient than that.

Comment: unable to access the actual values. I tried printing the values in the following manner  'print(variable_dict['lstm_1/kernel:0].kernel_f)'. This is just giving me the shapes not the actual values. How to get the actual values for the same?